# RcppGSL install fails on Google Colab (R notebook)

Tags: google-colaboratory, rcpp

`install.packages("RcppGSL")` results in

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
Warning message in install.packages("RcppGSL"):
“installation of package ‘RcppGSL’ had non-zero exit status”
```

[Edit: This is all. Colab doesn't print anything else. traceback() also returns just "No traceback available"]

on google colab.

You can open a R Notebook on Colab via [new Colab R notebook](http://colab.research.google.com/#create=true&language=r)

Edit 2: Solution

1. Open a *python* notebook in colab. You have to run a few terminal commands which doesn't work in the R version of colab-notebooks.
2. Run the following

```
!sudo apt install libgsl-dev
!pip install rpy2
%reload_ext rpy2.ipython
```

3. You can now run R code in cells by putting `%%R` at the top of the cell:

```
%%R
install.packages("RcppGSL")
library(RcppGSL)
rnorm(5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an incomplete post.  You do not show the *actual underlying error message* so we cannot help you.

Mostly likely, you simply forget to install the GSL development package. On a Debian/Ubuntu system this would be via

```
sudo apt install libgsl-dev
```

but if you have such a system you can even install the *prebuilt binary for RcppGSL* from the OS:

```
sudo apt install r-cran-rcppgsl
```

*Edit:* You may also need to consult the Google Colab documentation to assert *if* you can in fact install other (system) packages or not.  As an alternative, on RStudio Cloud (now a commercial product with limited free hours) you can install packages easily.  Maybe try your code there?

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware about RStudio Cloud.